# how to get a specific element while parsing with json_decode

Tags: php, json

I am parsing an image json from flickr

```
$jsrc = "https://api.flickr.com/services/rest/?text=Web&format=json&nojsoncallback=1&extras=url_l%2Curl_o%2Curl_z%2Curl_m&page=1&sort=relevance&api_key=cae293081d7db65b538c8bd4e90c988a&method=flickr.photos.search&per_page=10";
$json = file_get_contents($jsrc);
$jset = json_decode($json, true);
```

once I parse it I can only see a raw data
like `print_r($jset);`

I need to do something like

```
foreach($jset as $d) 
{ echo $d['owner'] ;}
```

I need to select a specific tag in this parsed Json Array list how I can do that ?

Comment: Could you post `json_decode` code to your question.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can run through the `array` like this:

```
$jsrc = "https://api.flickr.com/services/rest/?text=Web&format=json&nojsoncallback=1&extras=url_l%2Curl_o%2Curl_z%2Curl_m&page=1&sort=relevance&api_key=cae293081d7db65b538c8bd4e90c988a&method=flickr.photos.search&per_page=10";
$json = file_get_contents($jsrc);
$jset = json_decode($json, true);

echo "<pre>";

foreach ($jset['photos']['photo'] as $photo) {
    //print_r($photo);
    echo $photo['owner'];
    echo "<hr />";
}
```

Comment: okay this is good to understand what you get but I need to get only 'owner' inside $photo for example, how can I do that ?

Comment: @zyrag I have edited this answer.please see it. and accept answer.

Answer (score 0):

You can use this loop:

```
foreach ($jset['photos']['photo'] as $photo) {
  echo '<p><img src="' . $photo['url_o'] . '" /><br />Owner: ' . $photo['owner'] . '</p>';
}
```

The above will display the image with the owner underneath. You can tweak this as you need.

To access individual items, like the owner and the URL, you can change the index inside `$photo['']`.